# Java : Serializing an Object with Primitive Types. Get error java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, serialization, serializable

The Class definition

```
private class classSerial implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String vString;
    boolean vBool;
    long vLong;
    int vInt;

    classSerial(){
     //initialize members;
    }
}
```

I still get the error :

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.....
```

When I try to do a `writeObject` (using an object of `FileOutputStream`) on an object of `classSerial`.

---

From what I have read, the data types that I have used, `String`,`boolen`,`long`,`int` are `Serializable`. So, I do not need to implement any methods.

What is it that I am missing here?

---

LOGCAT

```
09-16 19:58:26.170: W/dalvikvm(4278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2165)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2160)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     ... 11 more
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.testing.serialActivity
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at com.example.testing.serialActivity.login(login_activity.java:277)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     at com.example.testing.serialtest.login(serialtest.java:34)
09-16 19:58:26.201: E/AndroidRuntime(4278):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?  It may include more hints.

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely to be that you have a inner class. i.e. its not static so it have a reference to the outer class which is not Serializable. This is why the check is there, to avoid serializing something you didn't intent to.

You will notice in the stack trace the class its complaining about is another class.

```
NotSerializableException: com.example.testingserialActivity
```

Try making the class

```
private static class ClassSerial implement Serializable
```

Comment: yes its a inner class. I will put the class in a separate file and test it out.

Comment: You can just make it static, but making it a top level class would also fix the problem.